# How to create a paragraph within one cell in MS Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to create content in MS Excel in one cell that comes from two other cells,
so like this:

```
=A1&&A2
```

What I wanna do now is separating the content in that new cell by a **paragraph** (... and not a standard **line break**...)

Anyone an idea, how to insert  a paragraph in a formula? @ Google I just found line breaks. :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post links and contents of what you found not useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CONCATENATE` with `CHAR(13)` (carriage return, line feed) then format the cell to Wrap Text

[image]

Edit - actually I think CHAR(10) will also work